# how to write a Regex to match phrase with varying no of spaces?

Tags: c#, regex, string

My regex doesn't give me the desired result...

I'm trying to parse a lengthy page with some words or sentences which are marked as '##word/sentence##'.

So my input is "##Unit## random text ##Unit Role## more random text ##The Unit Role## even more random text".

so i wrote a code that would allow me to capture the three words/sentences between the double hashes.

```
   string strSource= "##Unit## random text ##Unit Role## more random text ##The Unit Role## even more random text";
MatchCollection col = Regex.Matches(strSource, @"##([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)\##", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

string[] fields = new string[col.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
        {
            fields[i] = col[i].Groups[1].Value; // (Index 1 is the first group)
        }
```

However this only gives me "Unit" and "Unit Role". It skips "The Unit Role". Obviously this is because of the space, so how do i correct this?

Comment: I don't thinks it's your regex, but the way you extract the result. The regex works fine: https://regex101.com/r/nX4zD5/1

Comment: Ur right cholewa. Its my stupidity actually, The actual source had a ##Who are we?## apttern. So i edited my regex to ##([A-Za-z0-9\s\?]+)\## and now it works.

Comment: Perfect :-) Can you accept it as an answer if I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't thinks it's your regex, but the way you extract the result. The regex works fine: [regex101.com/r/nX4zD5/1](http://regex101.com/r/nX4zD5/1)

Comment: Is this the same as ##[\w\s\?]+##

Answer (score 1):

This regex worked on my machine and http://regexr.com/

```
##[\w\s]+##
```

Comment: This will accept '####'. I suggest '##[\w\s]+##' instead